# What is the difference between below mentioned two select query?

Tags: sql

```
select distinct TEXTVALUE as Market from Table_Name
```

and

```
select distinct Market from Table_Name
```

Both statement are giving some different value? Can anyone please elaborate why this is so?

Comment: are you having problem in understanding distinct or if you are thinking how two different query give different results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because both the queries are different.
In the query:

```
select distinct TEXTVALUE as Market from Table_Name
```

TEXTVALUE is the field name and Market is alias.  So you get distinct values in for the field TEXTVALUE and NOT Market field.

Whereas in the query:

```
select distinct Market from Table_Name
```

you are fetching distinct values from the Market field.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `distinct` in the query.

The `SELECT DISTINCT` statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

**The SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement**

In a table, a column may contain many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

so both query to specify column different it should be return result different.

**"select distinct TEXTVALUE as Market from Table_Name"** This query should be speciry textvalue column and market as alias name of output column. Distinct function work to textvalue not market.

**"select distinct Market from Table_Name"** This query should be specify column name market. Distinct function work to market column